# Is communication between processes really important for a OS or is it just a convenience?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

One of the services of a OS is communication between processes.However how much important is that?I dont think it is that important just for example if we saved a .txt file the file explorer wouldnt give back the name of the file to the text processor .Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of communication between processes that may not have occurred to you:

- Terminal I/O. Any text-based program needs to communicate with a terminal program somehow.
- Application control. Almost all modern operating systems have a way to communicate important information to running programs. This could be low-level information, such as if the system entered a low-power state, to high-level, such as if the global system colour scheme changed.
- System services, such as device drivers. Drivers usually have to interface with some kind of hardware, but they also need to communicate with the rest of the operating system in both directions.
- Debugging. A debugger needs to be able to control a debugged task in certain ways. (And just as an aside, OS textbooks almost *never* explain this.)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something here

Yes, you are.

> However how much important is that?

It is one of the most important problems when you write a multi-process program. It is quite complicated topic in programming and it is one of the most frequent sources of errors.

> I dont think it is that important just for example if we saved a .txt
> file the file explorer wouldnt give back the name of the file to the
> text processor

It is not communication between processes. The process is not a program you run from your desktop. Text processor or web browser uses many separate processes, task or threads. Communication between them and between them and OS is something we call IPC (interprocess communication).

Comment: Creating a different tab on a Browser is not multiprocessing , it is multithreading.